# Flexbox - dividers with vertically centered content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a container which I want to evenly space things out left to right and vertically center them. I would also like to add vertical dividers to between the content that would stretch if content gets longer.

This divider works just fine if content is not vertically centered:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 -8px;
}

section > * {
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.divider {
  width: 2px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  background: blue;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Potato</p>
  </div>    
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Markup</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

But when I add `align-items: center;`, the dividers disappear.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 -8px;
  align-items: center;
}

section > * {
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.divider {
  width: 2px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  background: blue;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Potato</p>
  </div>    
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Markup</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

How do I get the dividers back and have my content centered vertically?

Comment: Why don't you just add `text-align:center` to the `.item`? https://jsfiddle.net/95vz5ved/4/

Comment: @davidxc vertically centering

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set `align-items: center`, height of flex items is determined by its content, so you can use `align-self: stretch` on `divider` elements.

You can also use `align-self: center` on `item` element and remove `align-items: center` from flex-container. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vo8zeuLq/6/)

You can do the same with margins [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vo8zeuLq/10/)

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 -8px;
  align-items: center;
}
section>* {
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.divider {
  width: 2px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  background: blue;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.item {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Potato</p>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Markup</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is centered vertically. I did it a little differently. I am not a huge fan off Flexbox if I don't have to use it.

```css
section, .item {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 94.3%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

hr {
 border: 2px solid blue;
 }
section > * {
  margin: 0 1px;
}
.item {
  text-align: center;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Potato</p>
  </div> 
  <hr>
  <br>   
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Markup</p>
  </div>
</section>
```